# There is no clone git button in Jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-lab, git-clone

i´m taking Geo Python courses, and in one lesson they ask us to clone a repository from git hub. I have no problem cloning it from git hub, the problem is that my jupyter lab has no "cloning button".

i have tried the 3 different ways to install it from here https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git#install) and i am still not able to see the cloning button. I have attached a picture of how my jupyter lab looks.
what can i do to solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW0cs.png)

Comment: Is it related to https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git/pull/260? (from 2018, mybe it has changed since then)

Comment: It is related but instead of having a disabled git cloning button, I don´t have a button at all!

Comment: But  would you have that button when you are *outside* of any repository?

Comment: no, not button at all :/

Comment: Do you need to use the cloning button? Otherwise, you could clone the repository from the jupyterlab terminal